# Select list not displaying values and text

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Hi i'm just recently leaning java web development and im traying to display data from database to my drop down.

It is displaying the correct count of data's from DB but not displaying the text and values on the drop down

I'm sure that i put the correct `listKey="ID"` and `listValue="NAME"`
and as also check the list has values on debuging mode the `ID` and `NAME` has value

here's my .jsp

```
 <td >  
            <s:select list="UrgencyList"  listKey="ID" listValue="Name" 
                        name="Urgency" emptyOption="false" headerKey=""  required="true"
                        headerValue="--------------------------------------------------------" />  
                    <f

ont class="ui-widget-R"><s:property value="errors['Urgency'][0]" /></font>
        </td>
```

My Entity

```
public class UrgencyEntity {
//this class is created by kim ivan 2021-07026
    
    String ID="";
    String NAME="";
   
    public UrgencyEntity() {
    }

    
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }



    public void setID(String urgencyID) {
        this.ID = urgencyID;
    }
    
     public String getUName() {
            return NAME;
        }



        public void setUName(String UrgencyName) {
            this.NAME = UrgencyName;
        }
    
}
```

what am i missing or doing wrong i hope someone help me out with this

Comment: Do you have any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the issue is caused by inconsistent naming of the fields/getters/setters in the entity class and in JSP so they need to be changed to uniform `id` and `name`:

```java
// entity
public class UrgencyEntity {
    private String id = "";
    private String name = "";
   
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String urgencyID) { this.id = urgencyID; }
    
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String urgencyName) { this.name = urgencyName; }
}
```

JSP:

```
<td>  
    <s:select list="UrgencyList" listKey="id" listValue="name" 
              name="Urgency" emptyOption="false" headerKey=""  
              required="true" headerValue="------------------" />  
    <font class="ui-widget-R"><s:property value="errors['Urgency'][0]" /></font>
</td>
```

Comment: listvalue now displaying but the list key is not